# Laptop idling to unrecoverable black screen

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, wake-up

I have a HP ProBook 440 G4 that has had a problem where, when left idle for 5 minutes to a few hours, it simply will not wake up from the black screen - the only way to get it back online is to hold the power button which often causes application corruption. This has been happening since at least 2019/08/14.

Thus far, I have:

1. Checked the event logs "Application" and "System" but there is absolutely nothing relevant before the problem recurs.
2. Checked the power options but found that they're already configured to never go to sleep, hibernate, etc.
3. Checked the sole keyboard device `Standard 101/102-Key or Microsoft Natural PS/2 Keyboard for HP Hotkey Support` and found that it has no tab for power management and the drivers were already up to date.
4. Upgraded Windows 10 from v1809 to v1903.
5. Migrated from a HDD to an SSD (I had to do this anyway).
6. Ran the Windows Power Troubleshooter which found and “fixed” irrelevant issues (`Time before computer goes to sleep is too long` and `Display brightness setting is too high`).
7. Installed the latest versions of all available drivers and firmware:
   • Intel Chipset Installation Utility version 10.1.17809.8096 Rev.A released on 2019/03/04.
   • Realtek Ethernet Driver version 10.34.307.2019 Rev.A released on 2019/04/16.
   • HP Universal Camera Driver version 2016.10.16299.3 Rev.A released on 2018/02/02.
   • Intel WLAN Driver for Microsoft Windows 10 version 21.10.0.5 Rev.L released on 2019/05/23.
   • Intel Management Engine Driver version 1932.12.0.1298 Rev.W released on 2019/09/25.
   • HP Notebook System BIOS Update (P85,P91) version 01.31 Rev.A released on 2019/11/08.
8. Found that, when in this problematic state, the computer is still running (buttons lit up, fan whirring, etc) but it doesn't respond to anything (pressing buttons, unplugging cables, pinging the OS, connecting a monitor, etc).
9. From a Windows 10 v1903 DVD, run `sfc /scannow` which reported no integrity violations.
10. From a Windows 10 v1903 DVD, run `DISM /Image:D:\ /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` which reported `Completed successfully`.

I have now pretty much run out of ideas and nothing else I've found online has helped, hence this post.

**Update: 2019/11/19 12:50**

As advised by @JW0914, I have updated the driver for display adapter device "Intel® HD Graphics 620" from version 25.20.100.6472 released on 2018/12/10 to version 26.20.100.6888 Rev.W released on 2019/08/13.

I didn't think of doing this as (1) the HP Support Assistant didn't report that it could be updated so I thought it was already up-to-date and (2) the symptoms aren't what I would expect.

However, this does **seem** to have fixed the problem. I'll monitor it and report back.

Comment: One more try: Disable the screen-saver. You may set the screen to power off on idle in the Power Options.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks but I can't do that as it's against the company's security policy. In any case, the screen saver shouldn't cause these kinds of problems.

Comment: Have you tried setting the power button behavior to sleep in the power management settings, then pressing the power button to enter sleep mode when this occurs?  Does it then resume normally to the login screen?  What about the video drivers (I didn't see those in the list of drivers installed)?
 Windows 10 will auto-install all non-CPU (chipset, IMEI, etc.) related drivers upon running Windows Update, however this sounds a lot like behavior I've experienced on an Alienware laptop, but I never found what caused it, nor what resolved it. The way I worked around it was to use sleep mode (above)

Comment: @JW0914 Updating the graphics driver seems to have fixed the problem. Do you want to post that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the driver for display adapter device "Intel® HD Graphics 620" from version 25.20.100.6472 released on 2018/12/10 to version 26.20.100.6888 Rev.W released on 2019/08/13 did indeed resolve the problem.